# Call function when JSON.Parse() is ready?

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way to use an event to call a function when the JSON.Parse() has parsed all the objects from a file?

Comment: `JSON.parse()` does not load external file. It parses string representation of  `json` to `JavaScript object`. I assume you are asking something related `ajax`

Comment: also `JSON.parse` is synchronous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JSON.parse`  is synchronous.  it returns the object corresponding to the given JSON text.

More about it  from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

now a good way of doing JSON.parse is shown below (inside a try-catch)

```
try {
    var data = JSON.parse(string);
    //data is the object,
    //convert to object is completed here. you can call a function here passing created object                  
}
catch (err) {
    //mark this error ?
}
```

Now there are discussions, about why `JSON.parse` is not async, like the [ONE HERE](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/2uc7gv/its_2015_why_the_hell_is_jsonparse_synchronous/)

Comment: OK, so if I get this right, synchronous means that the code waits until all objects are parsed from the file and then continue running the code?

Comment: @front-back : Exactly,  please read the  reddit link, i shared. its about, why its not async

Comment: My thought was to use JSON.Parse() to "load" some data like objects for a game from a PHP file, instead of creating all object in the script. Is JSON.Parse() a good option for this?

Comment: @front-back : http://josh.zeigler.us/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/  .  its bit old, but a good read

Comment: Hmmm, old, can you suggest other options that is better and more up to date?

Comment: you can build up the object step-by-step. lets say create  bare minimum object to start the application. and in the background, build up the object using ajax.  also part of this object which is no more required can be deleted from this object

Comment: OK, I guess it's better to use XMLHttpRequest() then?

Comment: Does JSON.parse take main thread as it will block all other incoming events?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Since question was changed.**

JSON.parse() is a synchronous method, meaning that once it's called it will execute fully, before code execution continues.

```
var obj= JSON.parse(jsonString);
obj.prop; // obj is already accessible.
```

---

JSON.parse, doesn't actually load any files. It's also synchronous, meaning that code execution resume, after it has finished it's function, which is to parse a valid JSON string, to a JavaScript object.

If you want to execute a callback after a file has loaded, you'd need to look into requests, and ajax to be more precise. Here's a simple example using jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url/to/file.json',
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(yourCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer using plain Javascript for this project.